# OpenVAS installation and running errors

Tags: openvas

I've installed **Greenbone Security Assistant Version 9.0.1** (**OpenVAS**) by [this instruction](https://launchpad.net/%7Emrazavi/+archive/ubuntu/gvm) on my VirtualBox's Ubuntu 20.4.

```
sudo apt install postgresql    
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mrazavi/gvm
sudo apt install gvm    
greenbone-nvt-sync
sudo greenbone-scapdata-sync
sudo greenbone-certdata-sync
```

Unfortunately, it does not works.
When I'm trying to create a task by Wizard, I have the task completed just in moment, with an empty log. And that's all.

I've tried three commands:

```
systemctl status ospd-openvas # scanner
systemctl status gvmd # manager
systemctl status gsad # web ui
```

Everything is okay, except **ospd-openvas**. The status is green and active, but there are some errors too:

```
Jul 20 15:00:27 alex-VirtualBox ospd-openvas[833]: OSPD - openvas:
ERROR: (ospd_openvas.daemon) Failed to create feed lock file
/var/run/ospd/feed-update.lock. [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
'/var/run/ospd/feed-update.lock'
```

Comment: did my answer solve the issue or at least help you?

Answer (score 0):

From the error message it looks like the directory `/var/run/ospd/` does not exist.
Create the directory and try to restart the service.

In ubuntu 20.04 `/var/run` points to `/run` which is a temporary file system. That means that if you create the directory `/var/run/ospd` manually, it will be gone after the next reboot. To fix it permanently (in case the missing directory is the issue), please refer to [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/779634/create-a-directory-under-var-run-at-boot).

Answer (score 0):

This may help some people with some of the issues I've been facing:

```sh
mkdir -p /var/run/ospd/
touch /var/run/ospd/feed-update.lock
chown gvm:gvm /var/run/ospd/feed-update.lock
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

'gvm-feed-update'

it helps updating and syncing all data feeds needed